# Sharepoint + Javascript, moving/copying a list item to another folder

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, sharepoint

I'm looking into being able to automate a process where certain list items (xml files) in one of my document libraries are analyzed for certain data within the xml, then moved to a certain folder within the doc lib based on which type of data is found.

It's simple enough to setup some javascript to perform the analysis, but I'm stumped on how to transfer the document/listitem to another folder.  I am currently performing the analysis by putting my .js file in the same web folder as the list items that require analysis and executing the js from there.  The destination folders are also in this web folder.

Is there any way to use javascript to move a document within a web folder to another folder?  Note when I say folder I am talking about a folder that was created in the document library.

If this needs some clarity, feel free to ask.  I should note that I am using JS to do this because it would be an immediate solution, as opposed to writing SP Object Model code which needs to go through a long/painful deployment process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've not detailed which version of SharePoint your using.

If you are using SharePoint 2010 then this *may* be possible using the [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094%28office.14%29.aspx)

If you're using SharePoint 2007 then this may be possible using the [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation) project which allows you to use SharePoint's web services via javascript/jquery.

But I think you're on the wrong track here with javascript - this sounds like a scheduled task type operation so I think you would be better looking at a winforms/command line based solution than some javascript hack.

If deployment is such a pain then you may be able to use the [SharePoint Web Services](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_webservices/tutorials/article.php/c8805) (2003/2007 and 2010) so then you don't have to deploy this on the SharePoint server itself - it can be ran on any other machine.

Comment: Sorry about that, using SP 2007

Comment: The JS hack is only a temporary solution.  The plan is to get this solution within a timerjob/etc soon, but the deployment process is 1-2 months, so we need something in the meantime if it's possible.

Comment: I would still look at client based app via web services as a temp solution.